# How do I enable API Requests in Salesforce?

Tags: api, integration

Currently I am trying to locate a page to check/enable api support for my SalesForce developer instance (trial version).  I have not succeeded at locating the place where I enable API requests.

When going to api explorer in salesforce to send a request to my dev acct, I get a message ("API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG").

How do I get past this hurdle?

Comment: what api are you trying to use? can you add more details to your post?

Comment: I navigated to api explorer and ran AddAcceptedEventRelationById and CreateAccount for exmple when I got the error message API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a Developer Edition Trial. They are always free accounts. You've signed up for a Professional Edition or lower trial. Make sure you sign up from developerforce.com and not salesforce.com.

Comment: Unfortunately, I previously tried developerforce and signed up, it said my email was in use already.  When I used a new username I got, there was a problem with your account.  What do I do from here?  Do I simply log in to developer force with that info?  Also, when I tried to download developer edition I got no single link from salesforce to download.  I have even tried to contact salesforce to resolve this but cannot get through to a live support person.

Comment: @Vahe for developer accounts, you can use a different value than your email. For example, you might use myname@myname.dev as the user name. Make sure your email is correct though, or you won't be able to log in.